# $E(U_j,V_j)\leq\Delta/(2m)$ if probabilities of outcomes obtained from the approximate circuit is within a tolerance $Δ>0$

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, unitarity, universal-gates

> Suppose we wish to perform a quantum circuit containing $m$ gates, $U_1$ through $U_m$. Unfortunately, we are only able to approximate the gate $U_j$ by the gate $V_j$ . In order that the probabilities of different measurement outcomes obtained from the approximate circuit be within a tolerance $Δ>0$ of the correct probabilities, it suffices that $E(U_j,V_j)\leq\Delta/(2m)$

How do I make sense of this statement which is given in the section ["Approximating unitary operators" in Page 194 of QC and QI by Nelsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf).

It is proved in the same section that,

The probability of obtaining an outcome if $U$ (or $V$) is performed with a starting state $|\psi\rangle$ then $|P_U-P_V|\leq 2E(U,V)$, where $E(U,V)=\max_{|\psi\rangle}||(U-V)|\psi\rangle||=||U-V||$ is the error when $V$ is implemented instead of $U$.

And if we perform a sequence of gates $V_1,\cdots,V_m$ intended to approximate some other sequence of gates $U_1,\cdots,U_m$, then the errors add at most linearly, i.e., $E(U_m\cdots U_1,V_m\cdots V_1)\leq \sum_{j=1}^m E(U_j,V_j)$

How do I make use of these equations to validate the given statement ?

**My Try**

The statement, the probabilities of different measurement outcomes obtained from the approximate circuit be within a tolerance $Δ>0$ of the correct probabilities implies, $0\leq |P_{U_1\cdots U_m}-P_{V_1\cdots V_m}|\leq \Delta$